# Changing Intent.EXTRA_STREAM name on the fly

Tags: android

Im trying change "Intent.EXTRA_STREAM" file name on fly.
im using imageloader for loading image and it will cache file on local sdcard.
now im trying to attach these image to Email intent and send them.
problem is the name of file containg no extension and this cuz problem on other sharing mehtod like bluetoosh or some email hayoola .
the Imageloader get URL and Store them on Sdcard.
there is a function on Imageloader that i pass the URL and it return URI :

```
public Uri getUri(String url) 
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);
    return Uri.fromFile(f);
}
```

here is my code :

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, (imageloader.getUri(ImgUrl)));
```

now problem is this is the name of file returns without extension :

```
file:///mnt/sdcard/mygallery/896105659
```

i tried to add "+ ".png" " but it return error Java.lang.nullpointerexception

for url : its a normal image url : "http://www.ischgl.com/website/var/tmp/image-thumbnails/41395/thumb__lightbox/vider-alp_81712.jpeg"
im using this in FileCache :

```
String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
```

Comment: Could you show us one of your original URLs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found a WorkAround to change the name before attaching it:

```
File fileOutput=null;
        try {
            fileOutput = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "MyImage_.png");
            fileOutput.createNewFile();
            copyFile(Imageloader.getFile(ImageUrl), fileOutput);
        } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(fileOutput));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share)));
```

and for copy :

```
    void copyFile(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    FileChannel inChannel = new FileInputStream(src).getChannel();
    FileChannel outChannel = new FileOutputStream(dst).getChannel();
    try {
        inChannel.transferTo(0, inChannel.size(), outChannel);
    } finally {
        if (inChannel != null)
            inChannel.close();
        if (outChannel != null)
            outChannel.close();
    }
}
```